# How to stop dynamically added buttons from refreshing on form submit error HTML / jQuery

Tags: jquery, button, html-table, page-refresh

In my HTML page I have a button in each row of a table in a particular column. User may add new rows at runtime and these buttons are also inserted alongwith rest of the fields in each row.

**The buttons are being appended using the following:**

```
function funcAddBtnOpenPad() {
// VARS FOR ADDING BUTTON IN CELL "6"
// STORING BUTTON ATTRIBUTES
var btnOpenPad = $('<input/>').attr({ type: 'button', id:'idBtnOpenPad', class:'clsBtnOpenPad', name:'btnOpenPad', value:'Pad' });

$('#childTable tr').each(function(tempRowIdx) {
    
// CONSTRUCT TAG FOR BUTTON "Pad" IN CELL "6"
    tempButtonCellTag = 'id_tIndx'+tempRowIdx+6;

// HERE WE ARE INSERTING THE BUTTON "Pad" <<<<
        $('#'+ tempButtonCellTag).append(btnOpenPad);
        $(this).find("input[type='button']").attr('id', 'idBtnOpenPad'+tempRowIdx);
});
}
```

**The initial page** with a few rows added looks like this:

[image]

And with **some data filled in (in the last field) the table looks like this**:

[image]

This arrangement works **until an error is encountered on page submit** (say, due to a mandatory field not having been filled in by the user) when **all the buttons in the rows barring the last row disappear**, as shown below:

[image]

**How to stop the table refreshing so that the buttons do not disappear?**

Comment: Can you create working demo code ?

Comment: The arrangement is being used in Django app and the buttons (ref images) are part of inline formset. The data gets saved on page submit with all fields correctly filled in. The above cited problem occurs, only when it encounters **validation error**.

Comment: Yes if page gets refresh data which is added dynamically will disappear.. Also `form` submit will refresh your form ..can you do validation error client side if its just for checking null values?